# Passing data to SQL database through form in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, razor-pages, sweetalert2

I'm using a sweetalert2 to display a popup box where users can enter information. Upon clicking submit, it will send the data to my database. However, when clicking submit it errors out. The data doesn't get added to the database.

I've tried multiple different things for submitting the form such as a separate submit button and jquery form submit.

```
$('#btnAlert').click(function (e) {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Sign Out Device',
    html:
      '<form method="post" id="Form">' +
      '<input asp-for="Item.Name" id="Name" class="form-control" />' +
      '<input asp-for="Item.TimeOut" id="TimeOut" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" readonly />' +
      '<input asp-for="Item.Desc" id="Desc" class="form-control" />' +
      '</form>',
    focusConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
    preConfirm: () => {
      let Name = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#Name').value
      let Description = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#Desc').value
      let Date = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#TimeOut').value
      if (Name === '' || Description === '') {
        Swal.showValidationMessage('Please fill in all fields')
      }
    },
    onClose: () => {
      document.getElementById("Form").submit()
    }
  })
});
```

Heres the error message:
This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 400

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have an error message you could add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error happens because you are not passing a [request verification token](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#ajax-post-requests-and-json) in your form post, which Razor Pages expects.

In addition, the HTML that you are passing to the `fire` method is not standard. It looks like Razor tag helpers, which is only useful in the context of a *cshtml* page that gets processed by the Razor Pages framework. It is not useful as a string, passed to a JavaScript method. You should change the tag helpers to standard HTML inputs with appropriate `name` attributes.